# Invalid Request on Upgrading Firebase App Check plugin

Tags: flutter, firebase-app-check

I have been using Firebase app Check plugin in my project(Android Only).
Recently i upgraded the plugin from 0.0.7+1 to 0.1.1+4 and it broke. Now i am not able to use AppCheck in my projects and it say invalid request.
What is the proper way to upgrade this package without any breaking changes

I have tried almost everything

1. firebase init
2. flutterfire configure
3. flutter clean
4. reinstalling App

Comment: If there is a breaking change in the librarie's API from 0.0.7 to 0.1.1 you cannot change that. Either chose a lower version that 0.1.1. that is still compatible or port your code to the new version

Comment: That's what i am looking for : port your code to the new version